# Change color of result using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently making a page that outputs data from a mysql database onto a page using php like so:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:18px'>Physical</span></td><td><span style='font-size:18px;'>" . $row['attributePhy'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;'>Jumping </span></td><td><span style='font-size:14px;'>" . $row['jumping'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;'>Stamina </span></td><td><span style='font-size:14px;'>" . $row['stamina'] . "</span></span></td>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;'>Strength </span></td><td><span style='font-size:14px;'>" . $row['strength'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;'>Aggression </span></td><td><span style='font-size:14px;'>" . $row['aggression'] . "</span></td>";
```

However I want it so the color of the number result changes based on how high the number is e.g. red is 60 and below, light green is 61 to 80 and dark green is 81+

Is there any way to do this for the entire table? The above code is just a small sample and doing if statements for each one would take a long time.

Edit:

I only want to change the result color e.g.

```
<span style='font-size:14px;'>" . $row['aggression'] . "</span>
<span style='font-size:14px;'>" . $row['strength'] . "</span>
```

This returns as a number for the database which is the bit that needs to change color.
etc

Comment: Just the result e.g. <span style='font-size:14px;'>" . $row['aggression'] . "</span>

Comment: something like: echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;".if($row['aggression'] == 61){"background-color:red;"}."'>Aggression </span></td><td><span style='font-size:14px;'>" . $row['aggression'] . "</span></td>";

Comment: The first part is the "title"

Comment: Does `$row['attributePhy']` return the number that you want to use to change the colour?

Comment: @WillParky93 Yes

Comment: Non of your `<tr>` are closed. That's why i said that share your full code along with desired table screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you need a conditional statement:
in this example i'll use the ternary operator:

```
function getColor($value){
    return ($value <= 60 ?
                'color: red;' 
                : 
                ($value > 60 && $value < 81  ?
                    'color: lightgreen;'
                    :
                    ($value >= 81 ?
                        'color: darkgreen' 
                        :
                        ''
                    )
                )
            );
}
```

and you can use it as follow:

```
echo "<td><span style='font-size:18px;". getColor($row['attributePhy'])."'>" . $row['attributePhy'] . "</span></td>";
```

Comment: This works great using this:

echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:18px'>Physical</span></td><td><span style='font-size:18px;". getColor($row['attributePhy'])."'>" . $row['attributePhy'] . "</span></td>";

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function changecolor($val) {
if ($val <= 60) {
echo "<font color='red'>$val</font>";
}
elseif ($val >60 AND $val <80) {
echo "<font color='lightgreen'>$val</font>";
}
else
{
echo "<font color='darkgreen'>$val</font>";     
}
}
```

Then:

```
<span style='font-size:14px;'>" . changecolor($row['aggression']) . "</span>
<span style='font-size:14px;'>" . changecolor($row['strength']) . "</span>
```

Comment: This works but seems to move the result out of the row [Here](http://imgur.com/a/GyODo) you can see the bottom 4 results have this applied and have moved.

Comment: did you put it inside a '<td>' tag? Like : <td><span style='font-size:14px;'>" . changecolor($row['aggression']) . "</span></td>

Comment: Yes I used this:
echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;'>Aggression </span></td><td><span style='font-size:14px;'>" . changecolor($row['aggression']) . "</span></td>";

Comment: But OP doesn't need `if`. Read the question _The above code is just a small sample and doing if statements for each one would take a long time._

Comment: @peak  none of your `<tr>` is closed that'e why you are getting problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to this utility function:

You can all this something like: `getColor($row['aggression'])` or `getColor($row['strength'])`

```
function getColor($value)
{
    $possibilities = [
        'red'         => 0,
        'light green' => 60,
        'dark green'  => 80
    ]; // Add all your possibilities with the lower end match here like 0, 60, 80...

    return array_search(max(array_intersect($possibilities, range(0, $value))), $possibilities);

}

echo getColor(11);  // red
echo getColor(61);  // light green
echo getColor(81);  // dark green
echo getColor(801); // dark green
echo getColor(80);  // dark green
```

Use like this:

```
echo "<td><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;background-color:" . getColor($row['aggression']) . ";'>Aggression </span></td><td><span style='font - size:14px;'>" . $row['aggression'] . "</span></td>";
```

---

**Explanation:**

1. `range` will create array of possibilities
2. `array_intersect` returns the matches that is in the possibility array
3. `max` returns the maximum value
4. `array_search` gets the key for the match